# " Error (10822): HDL error at pong_game.vhd(350): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge"

Tags: vhdl

I have recently created a pong game in VHDL, the simulation looks pretty and the game behaves well. The game is a 1 vs 1. Each player has a a racket symbolized by two lit leds above and below the led matrix.

The ball is symbolized by lit leds scrolling at the ends of the led matrix and they have to be punched by the rackets displayed by two push buttons ( a left button and a right button for each player).

I'm using a cpld maxII equipped with a 50 Mhz clock. So i divided the frequency to control the scrolling of the leds.

After i have played many games with my little sister (she enjoyed it a lot :D), I decided make it funnier. The idea is to variate the frequency of the scrolling leds after 3,6,9,12,15 pushed balls. When the counter (named cnt_win) is below 3, the scrolling is slow and the frequency is increasing untill the cnt_win reaches 15. When one player fails the counter equals 0 ...

I use many clocks  to variate the frequency and made the game more attracive but it doesn't work due to the error " Error (10822): HDL error at pong_game.vhd(350): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge".

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity pong_game is 

port(
         d1 : in std_logic; -- right push button player 1
         g1 : in std_logic; -- left  push button player 1
         d2 : in std_logic; -- "               " player 2
         g2 : in std_logic; -- "               " player 2
         clk_50Mhz : in std_logic;
         clk_20hz : buffer std_logic :='0';
         RST : in std_logic;  -- reset button
         leds : buffer std_logic_vector (30 downto 1);
         led_barre_2 : buffer std_logic_vector (5 downto 1):="00011";
         led_barre_1 : buffer std_logic_vector (5 downto 1):="00011"  
         );

end pong_game;

architecture pong_game_arch of pong_game is
constant position1 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 1) := "00011";
constant position2 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 1) := "00110";
constant position3 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 1) := "01100";
constant position4 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 1) := "11000";

type etat is (led1,led2,led3,led4,led5,led6_1,led7_1_g,led7_1_d,led8_1_g,led8_1_d,led9_1_g,led9_1_d,led10_1,led11_1,led12_1_g,led12_1_d,led13_1_g,led13_1_d,led14_1_g,led14_1_d,led15_1,    
            led16_1,led17_1_g,led17_1_d,led18_1_g,led18_1_d,led19_1_g,led19_1_d,led20_1,led21_1,led22_1_g,led22_1_d,led23_1_g,led23_1_d,led24_1_g,led24_1_d,led25_1,led26,led27,led28,led29,led30,
            led6_2,led7_2_g,led7_2_d,led8_2_g,led8_2_d,led9_2_g,led9_2_d,led10_2,led11_2,led12_2_g,led12_2_d,led13_2_g,led13_2_d,led14_2_g,led14_2_d,led15_2,led16_2,led17_2_g,led17_2_d,led18_2_g,led18_2_d,led19_2_g,led19_2_d,
            led20_2,led21_2,led22_2_g,led22_2_d,led23_2_g,led23_2_d,led24_2_g,led24_2_d,led25_2,        
            led6_init,
            led7_init,
            led8_init,
            led9_init,
            led10_init,
            led11_init_1,
            led11_init_2,
            led12_init_1,
            led12_init_2,
            led13_init_1,
            led13_init_2,
            led14_init_1,
            led14_init_2,
            led15_init_1,
            led15_init_2,        -- Sequence led initiale
            led16_init_1,
            led16_init_2,
            led17_init_1,
            led17_init_2,
            led18_init_1,
            led18_init_2,
            led19_init_1,
            led19_init_2,
            led20_init_1,
            led20_init_2,
            led21_init,
            led22_init,
            led23_init,
            led24_init,
            led25_init,
            all_led_loose_on,
            all_led_loose_off);

signal etat_present, etat_futur : etat :=led11_init_1; -- etat initial

signal cnt : integer range 11 to 20 :=11; -- Permet de choisir quelle led initial

signal cnt1 : integer range 3 downto 0 :=0; -- gère les positions de led_barre_1
signal cnt2 : integer range 3 downto 0 :=0; -- idem pour led_barre_2

--signal clk_20hz : std_logic :='0'; -- gère les boutons poussoirs gauche-droite

---------  gère les sequences de leds avec 4 signals d'horloge  -----------

signal clk_0 : std_logic :='0'; -- niveau lent
signal clk_1 : std_logic :='0'; -- niveau normal    
signal clk_2 : std_logic :='0'; -- niveau rapide
signal clk_3 : std_logic :='0'; -- niveau très rapide



signal cnt_clk_20 : std_logic_vector  (22 downto 1):= (others=>'0');
signal cnt_clk_0  : std_logic_vector  (25 downto 1):= (others=>'0');
signal cnt_clk_1  : std_logic_vector  (24 downto 1):= (others=>'0');
signal cnt_clk_2  : std_logic_vector  (24 downto 1):= (others=>'0');
signal cnt_clk_3  : std_logic_vector  (24 downto 1):= (others=>'0');

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------  choix binaire des fréquences de défilements --------------------------

constant lent     : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) :="00";
constant normal   : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) :="01";
constant rapide   : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) :="10";
constant rapide_v : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) :="11";

signal choix      : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) :=lent;

signal cnt_win    : integer range 15 downto 0 :=0;

begin

diviseur_clk : process(clk_50Mhz)

                begin 

                    if rising_edge(clk_50Mhz) then

                        if cnt_clk_0 < "1011111010111100001000000" then  --25.000.000
                            cnt_clk_0 <= cnt_clk_0+'1';
                        else
                            clk_0<=not(clk_0);
                            cnt_clk_0<= (others => '0');
                        end if;

                        if cnt_clk_1 < "111001001110000111000000" then  --15.000.000
                            cnt_clk_1<=cnt_clk_1+'1';
                        else
                            clk_1<=not(clk_1);
                            cnt_clk_1<= (others =>'0');
                        end if;

                        if cnt_clk_2 < "100110001001011010000000" then  --10.000.000
                            cnt_clk_2<=cnt_clk_2+'1';
                        else
                            clk_2<=not(clk_2);
                            cnt_clk_2<= (others=>'0');
                        end if;

                        if cnt_clk_3 < "11100100111000011100000" then  --7.500.000
                            cnt_clk_3 <= cnt_clk_3+'1';
                        else
                            clk_3<=not(clk_3);
                            cnt_clk_3<= (others=>'0');
                        end if;

                        if cnt_clk_20 < "1001100010010110100000" then --2.500.000
                            cnt_clk_20<=cnt_clk_20+'1';
                        else
                            clk_20hz<=not(clk_20hz);
                            cnt_clk_20<= (others =>'0');
                        end if;

                    end if;-- rising_edge


end process diviseur_clk ;

position_1 : process (clk_20hz,d1,g1)

begin

    if rising_edge(clk_20hz) then

case cnt1 is

        when 0=>

    if d1='1' and g1='0' then

    led_barre_1<="00110";

        cnt1<=1;

    end if;

        when 1=>

    if d1='1' and g1='0' then

    led_barre_1<="01100";

    cnt1<=2;



    elsif d1='0' and g1='1' then

    led_barre_1<="00011";

    cnt1<=0;

    end if;



        when 2=>

    if d1='1' and g1='0' then

    led_barre_1<="11000";

        cnt1<=3;

    elsif d1='0' and g1='1' then

    led_barre_1<="00110";

        cnt1<=1;

    end if;

        when 3 =>

        if d1='0' and g1='1' then

        led_barre_1<="01100";

        cnt1<=2;

        end if;

        when others =>

        end case;

        end if;

end process position_1;

position_2 : process (clk_20hz,d2,g2)

begin

    if rising_edge(clk_20hz) then

case cnt2 is

        when 0=>

    if d2='1' and g2='0' then

    led_barre_2<="00110";

        cnt2<=1;

    end if;

        when 1=>

    if d2='1' and g2='0' then

    led_barre_2<="01100";

    cnt2<=2;



    elsif d2='0' and g2='1' then

    led_barre_2<="00011";

    cnt2<=0;

    end if;



        when 2=>

    if d2='1' and g2='0' then

    led_barre_2<="11000";

        cnt2<=3;

    elsif d2='0' and g2='1' then

    led_barre_2<="00110";

        cnt2<=1;

    end if;

        when 3 =>

        if d2='0' and g2='1' then

        led_barre_2<="01100";

        cnt2<=2;
        end if;

        when others =>

        end case;

        end if;

end process position_2;

--end architecture pong_game_arch;


--architecture led_matrix of pong_game is 


compteur : process(clk_50Mhz)

begin

    if rising_edge(clk_50Mhz) then

        if cnt < 20 then

            cnt<= cnt+1;

        else

            cnt<=11;

        end if;

    end if;

end process compteur ;


initialisation : process(RST,clk_0,clk_1,clk_2,clk_3)

begin


    if RST='1' then

        case cnt is 

            when 11 => etat_present <= led11_init_1;
            when 12 => etat_present <= led12_init_1;
            when 13 => etat_present <= led13_init_1;
            when 14 => etat_present <= led14_init_1;
            when 15 => etat_present <= led15_init_1;
            when 16 => etat_present <= led16_init_2;
            when 17 => etat_present <= led17_init_2;
            when 18 => etat_present <= led18_init_2;
            when 19 => etat_present <= led19_init_2;
            when 20 => etat_present <= led20_init_2;

        end case ;

    else 

        case choix is

            when lent =>                             -- choice of the 
                                                     -- frequency (the error 
                                                     -- occurs here )

                if rising_edge(clk_0) then

                    etat_present <= etat_futur;

                end if;

            when normal =>

                if rising_edge(clk_1) then

                    etat_present <= etat_futur;

                end if;

            when rapide =>

                if rising_edge(clk_2) then

                etat_present <= etat_futur;

                end if;

            when rapide_v =>

                if rising_edge(clk_3) then

                etat_present <= etat_futur;

                end if;

            end case ;

    end if;

end process initialisation ;

sequence_led : process(etat_present,led_barre_1,led_barre_2)

begin

case etat_present is

-- sequence initiale

when led6_init =>

    etat_futur <= led1;

when led7_init =>

    etat_futur <= led2;

when led8_init =>

    etat_futur <= led3;

when led9_init =>

    etat_futur <= led4;

when led10_init =>

    etat_futur <= led5;


when led11_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led6_init;

when led12_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led7_init;

when led13_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led8_init;

when led14_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led9_init;

when led15_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led10_init;

when led16_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led11_init_2;

when led17_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led12_init_2;

when led18_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led13_init_2;

when led19_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led14_init_2;

when led20_init_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led15_init_2;

when led11_init_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led16_init_1;

when led12_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led17_init_1;

when led13_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led18_init_1;

when led14_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led19_init_1;

when led15_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led20_init_1;

when led16_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led21_init;

when led17_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led22_init;

when led18_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led23_init;

when led19_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led24_init;

when led20_init_1 =>

        etat_futur <= led25_init;

when led21_init =>

        etat_futur <= led26;

when led22_init => 

        etat_futur <= led27;

when led23_init =>

        etat_futur <= led28;

when led24_init =>

        etat_futur <= led29;

when led25_init =>

        etat_futur <= led30;

-- fin sequence initiale

when led1 =>

    if led_barre_1 = position1 then

        etat_futur <= led7_1_d;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    else

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;
        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;


when led2 =>

    if led_barre_1 = position1 then

        etat_futur <= led8_1_d;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    elsif led_barre_1 = position2 then

        etat_futur <= led6_1;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    else 

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led3 =>

    if led_barre_1 = position2 then

        etat_futur <= led9_1_d;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    elsif led_barre_1 = position3 then

        etat_futur <= led7_1_g;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    else


        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led4 =>

    if led_barre_1 = position3 then

        etat_futur <= led10_1;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    elsif led_barre_1 = position4 then

        etat_futur <= led8_1_g;

            if cnt_win < 15 then 

                cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

            end if;

    else

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led5=>

    if led_barre_1 = position4 then

        etat_futur <= led9_1_g;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if; 

    else

        etat_futur<= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led6_1=>

    etat_futur <= led12_1_d;

when led6_2=>

    etat_futur <= led2;

when led7_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led11_1;

when led7_1_d=>

    etat_futur <= led13_1_d;

when led7_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led1;

when led7_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led3;

when led8_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led12_1_g;

when led8_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led14_1_d;

when led8_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led2;

when led8_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led4;

when led9_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led13_1_g;

when led9_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led15_1;

when led9_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led3;

when led9_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led5;

when led10_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led14_1_g;

when led10_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led4;

when led11_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led17_1_d;

when led11_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led7_2_d;

when led12_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led16_1;

when led12_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led18_1_d;

when led12_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led6_2;

when led12_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led8_2_d;

when led13_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led17_1_g;

when led13_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led19_1_d;

when led13_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led7_2_g;

when led13_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led9_2_d;

when led14_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led18_1_g;

when led14_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led20_1;

when led14_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led8_2_g;

when led14_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led10_2;

when led15_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led19_1_g;

when led15_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led9_2_g;

when led16_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led22_1_d;

when led16_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led12_2_d;

when led17_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led21_1;

when led17_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led23_1_d;

when led17_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led11_2;

when led17_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led13_2_d;

when led18_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led22_1_g;

when led18_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led24_1_d;

when led18_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led12_2_g;

when led18_2_d=>

    etat_futur <= led14_2_d;

when led19_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led23_1_g;

when led19_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led25_1;

when led19_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led13_2_g;

when led19_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led15_2;

when led20_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led24_1_g;

when led20_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led14_2_g;

when led21_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led27;

when led21_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led17_2_d;

when led22_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led26;

when led22_1_d=>

    etat_futur <= led28;

when led22_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led16_2;

when led22_2_d=>

    etat_futur <= led18_2_d;

when led23_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led27;

when led23_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led29;

when led23_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led17_2_g;

when led23_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led19_2_d;

when led24_1_g =>

    etat_futur <= led28;

when led24_1_d =>

    etat_futur <= led30;

when led24_2_g =>

    etat_futur <= led18_2_g;

when led24_2_d =>

    etat_futur <= led20_2;

when led25_1 =>

    etat_futur <= led29;

when led25_2 =>

    etat_futur <= led19_2_g;

when led26 =>

    if led_barre_2=position1 then

        etat_futur<=led22_2_d;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    else --loose

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led27 =>

    if led_barre_2=position1 then

        etat_futur<=led23_2_d;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    elsif led_barre_2=position2 then

        etat_futur<=led21_2;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    else --loose

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;
    end if;

when led28 =>

    if led_barre_2=position2 then

        etat_futur <= led24_2_d;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    elsif led_barre_2=position3 then

        etat_futur <= led22_2_g;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    else 

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led29 =>

    if led_barre_2 = position4 then

    etat_futur <= led23_2_g;

    if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

    end if;

    elsif led_barre_2 = position3 then

    etat_futur <= led25_2;

    if cnt_win < 15 then 

        cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

    end if;

    else

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when led30 =>

    if led_barre_2 = position4 then

        etat_futur <= led24_2_g;

        if cnt_win < 15 then 

            cnt_win <= cnt_win + 1;

        end if;

    else

        etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

        cnt_win <= 0;

    end if;

when all_led_loose_on =>                       -- cycle entre ces deux états

    etat_futur <= all_led_loose_off;                  -- jusqu'à ce que RST = '1'

when all_led_loose_off =>

    etat_futur <= all_led_loose_on;

end case ;

end process sequence_led ;


affichage_sequence : process(etat_present)
begin

case etat_present is

when led1 =>

    leds <= ( 1 => '1', others => '0');

when led2 =>

    leds <= ( 2 => '1', others => '0');

when led3 =>

    leds <= ( 3 => '1', others => '0');

when led4 =>

    leds <= ( 4 => '1', others => '0');

when led5=>

    leds <= ( 5 => '1', others => '0');

when led6_1|led6_2|led6_init=>

    leds <= ( 6 => '1', others => '0');

when led7_1_d|led7_1_g|led7_2_d|led7_2_g|led7_init =>

    leds <= ( 7 => '1', others => '0');

when led8_1_d|led8_1_g|led8_2_d|led8_2_g|led8_init =>

    leds <= ( 8 => '1', others => '0');

when led9_1_d|led9_1_g|led9_2_d|led9_2_g|led9_init =>

    leds <= ( 9 => '1', others => '0');

when led10_1|led10_2|led10_init =>

    leds <= ( 10 => '1', others => '0');

when led11_1|led11_2|led11_init_1|led11_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 11 => '1', others => '0');

when led12_1_g|led12_1_d|led12_2_g|led12_2_d|led12_init_1|led12_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 12 => '1', others => '0');

when led13_1_g|led13_1_d|led13_2_g|led13_2_d|led13_init_1|led13_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 13 => '1', others => '0');

when led14_1_d|led14_1_g|led14_2_g|led14_2_d|led14_init_1|led14_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 14 => '1', others => '0');

when led15_1|led15_2|led15_init_1|led15_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 15 => '1', others => '0');

when led16_1|led16_2|led16_init_1|led16_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 16 => '1', others => '0');

when led17_1_g|led17_1_d|led17_2_g|led17_2_d|led17_init_1|led17_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 17 => '1', others => '0');

when led18_1_g|led18_1_d|led18_2_g|led18_2_d|led18_init_1|led18_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 18 => '1', others => '0');

when led19_1_g|led19_1_d|led19_2_g|led19_2_d|led19_init_1|led19_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 19 => '1', others => '0');

when led20_1|led20_2|led20_init_1|led20_init_2 =>

    leds <= ( 20 => '1', others => '0');

when led21_1|led21_2|led21_init =>

    leds <= ( 21 => '1', others => '0');

when led22_1_g|led22_1_d|led22_2_g|led22_2_d|led22_init =>

    leds <= ( 22 => '1', others => '0');

when led23_1_g|led23_1_d|led23_2_g|led23_2_d|led23_init =>

    leds <= ( 23 => '1', others => '0');

when led24_1_g|led24_1_d|led24_2_g|led24_2_d|led24_init =>

    leds <= ( 24 => '1', others => '0');

when led25_1|led25_2|led25_init =>

    leds <= ( 25 => '1', others => '0');

when led26 =>

    leds <= ( 26 => '1', others => '0');

when led27 =>

    leds <= ( 27 => '1', others => '0');

when led28 =>

    leds <= ( 28 => '1', others => '0');

when led29 =>

    leds <= ( 29 => '1', others => '0');

when led30 =>

    leds <= ( 30 => '1', others => '0');

when all_led_loose_on =>

    leds <= (others =>'1');

when all_led_loose_off =>

    leds <= (others =>'0');

end case ;

end process affichage_sequence ;
variation_frequence : process (cnt_win) 
begin

case cnt_win is 

when 0|1|2|3  => choix <= lent ;
when 4|5|6    => choix <= normal ;
when 7|8|9    => choix <= rapide ;
when 10|11|12 => choix <= normal ;
when 13|14|15 => choix <= rapide_v;
end case;
end process variation_frequence ;
end architecture pong_game_arch;
```

The error occurs at the process "initialisation".

Comment: The error relates to using multiple clocks to store the same datum. It doesn't reflect a synthesis eligible construct representing sequential hardware (e.g. flip flops). Instead of multiple clocks you could generate an enable at different rates. Supported sequential logic constructs are derived from the now withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis standard and are described in Altera/Intel documentation which should likely be viewed as a first resource for errors.

Comment: VHDL tagged [posts containing 'error 10822 ' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvhdl%5D+Error+%2810822%29).

Comment: Yes, I decided here to publish all my code.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what user1155120 used said in his comment you also did a very bad thing (unless you're doing ASICs) which is clock gating. You should not derive clocks from combinatorial logic. Only clock sources such as clock pins and PLLs. In my opinion the best way to change the code is to do a rising edge detection on the signals (don't call them clocks) clk_0, clk_1, clk_2 and clk_3. Use these "rising edges" in your if statements (lines 351, 359, 367 and 375). The main problem with this approach is you're adding at least one latency cycle to the flow which might or might not impact your final output. You have to adjust for this somehow.

Comment: This is not written as an answer, but more as a comment. Could you please improve.